# How do I return to my primary display (A) if I go from screen A to B to C back to B using unwindSegue

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I currently am learning how to program in Swift and have made 3 different pages; `Pages A, B, and C`. From `page A`, I am able to navigate to `page B`, and from `page B`, I am able to go to either `page C` or `page A`. When I go to `page C` I can go back to `page B` or `page A`.

The issue that I am running into however is that if I go from `Page A` to `Page B` to `Page C` back to `Page B`, when I try to close `Page B`, it would display `Page C` briefly before closing back to `page A`.

All of these are on separate `viewcontrollers` and I've just been presenting all of them modally each time

I've tried using [Unwind Segues Step-by-Step](https://matteomanferdini.com/unwind-segue/#jumping)  and [Create Unwind Segues in Swift 3](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f)
 to understand what I've been doing wrong, however from what I've read on them (and from my limited knowledge of Swift), none of them discuss going back a single page and then trying to close after. They all go from `1 -> 2 -> 3` back to `1` without the intermediate step of going back to `page 2`.

`@IBAction func close (_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue){}` is what I've been using as my unwindSegues linking these up to my Exit placeholder. This was done on both `Pages B and C`

Currently there is no error message, it appears to work but it does show that intermediate screen which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share project code?

Comment: Without looking at your code, it is unlikely to tell what you've done wrong. Upload it somewhere (maybe [GitHub](https://github.com) ) and share the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> when I tap on the back button on page C -> B it shows that I trigger an Action that presents Modally (if that helps)

That is precisely the problem. Having gone from A to B to C, C should not then modally present B again. You’re creating a new, second instance of B. You’d have a view controller hierarchy that looks like:

> A » B1 » C » B2

If, though, you successfully dismissed/unwound from C to B, you would have ended up with only A and B in the view controller hierarchy:

> A » B

And then, when B went to dismiss/unwind to A, C would be long gone and there’s no way you’d see it in your animation.

---

If you’re using unwind segues, I’d suggest that view controller A had an unwind action like so:

```
@IBAction func unwindToA(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

And view controller B could have an unwind action like so:

```
@IBAction func unwindToB(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

Now, when C wants to unwind back to B, if you could use the latter unwind action. If you want to unwind to A (either from B or C), you could use the former one.

Just make sure that you never present/show when you want to go backwards in the view controller hierarchy. Either use unwind segues, or `dismiss`/`pop` as appropriate.

Comment: Ahh this seemed to be the problem! Thanks you very much and I do apologize for the confusion with my description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. But I guess your problem is you used present instead of dismiss when you back to B from C.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear as this is my first time posting along with trying to program. As for this comment, I believe it's accurate as when I go to XCode, I see that when I tap on the `back` button on page C -> B it shows that I trigger an Action that presents Modally (if that helps)

Answer (score 0):

Seems quite confusing question description.

**Not sure but maybe you have mistakenly added segue from Page B -> C on the same Back button. Please check that also.**

I've created `SimpleUnwindExample` project on GitHub. Hope It will help in to fix your issue.

Repository Link: https://github.com/harshal-wani/SimpleUnwindExample

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your  question is not fully clear to me . So far I understand if you wanna back from C to B View Controller , then you can do it Simply use

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

in Your Exit Button action . Hopefully it will help .